# How to deploy on mainnet using anchor?

Tags: anchor, deploy, mainnet

Can someone who lately successfully deployed program to mainnet say what versions of solana-cli, anchor-cli,... did you use?
When I try to deploy, it takes ages (on devnet its in 1 minute done) and in the end it fails with `Error: Data writes to account failed: Custom error: Max retries exceeded`.

I am using quicknode rpc, trying to upgrade/downgrade solana/anchor, but yet without success.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by add flag --with-compute-unit-price 1 (you can change 1 to any unit price you one, 1  = 1 microlamport). This flag will add priority fee for all your deployed tx. Just use the latest version solana cli 1.18.8
try this

> anchor build

> solana program deploy ./target/deploy/<..>.so --with-compute-unit-price 5

Solana CLI just update to apply priority fee for all tx.